# How to find a function that can approximate another blackbox function programmaticly?

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, approximation, regression, applications

This question has been posted on

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758016/how-to-find-a-function-that-can-approximate-another-blackbox-function-programmat

I was suggested to post it here.

I have two functions

```
m1 = f1(w, s)
m2 = f2(w, s)
```

f1() and f2() are all blackboxs. Given w and s, I can get m1 and m2.

Now, I need to design or find a function g, such that

```
 m2' = g(m1)

 Also, the difference between m2 and m2' must be minimized.
```

The w and s are all stochastic process.

How can I find such a function g()? What knowledge domain does this belong to ?